# OpenCV frame drop with Realsense

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, intel, realsense

Hi I've been working on a object detection script with distance calculation. I'm using a realsense D455-C camera. I found a demo using OpenCV with object detection and just added some distance calculations. The problem I have is that the framerate drops to like 5-8fps, this only happens when I run the object detection, I have another script that just runs the normal color stream and depth and it runs smoothly at 30fps. I've searched about this issue but don't find anything helpful, any help would be much appreciated!

```
import pyrealsense2 as rs
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

# Configure depth and color streams
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config = rs.config()
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 1280, 720, rs.format.bgr8, 30)
dec_filter = rs.decimation_filter()
print("[INFO] Starting streaming...")
config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 1280, 720, rs.format.z16, 30)
pipeline.start(config)
print("[INFO] Camera ready.")

# download model from: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API#run-network-in-opencv
print("[INFO] Loading model...")
PATH_TO_CKPT = "C:/Testing Camera/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/frozen_inference_graph.pb"

# Load the Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    with tf.compat.v1.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph)

# Input tensor is the image
image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
# Output tensors are the detection boxes, scores, and classes
# Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected
detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
# Each score represents level of confidence for each of the objects.
# The score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
# Number of objects detected
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
# code source of tensorflow model loading: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-training-image-classifier-using-tensorflow-object-detection-api/
print("[INFO] Model loaded.")
colors_hash = {}

while True:
    frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
    color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()
    depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame()
    # Convert images to numpy arrays
    color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())
    scaled_size = (color_frame.width, color_frame.height)
    # expand image dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
    image_expanded = np.expand_dims(color_image, axis=0)
    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run([detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
                                                feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})

    boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
    classes = np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32)
    scores = np.squeeze(scores)
    depth_image = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data())
    for idx in range(int(num)):
        class_ = classes[idx]
        score = scores[idx]
        box = boxes[idx]
        
        if class_ not in colors_hash:
            colors_hash[class_] = tuple(np.random.choice(range(256), size=3))
        
        if score > 0.6: #Sensitivity of the detection Default is 0.6
            
            left = int(box[4] * color_frame.width)#x
            top = int(box[0] * color_frame.height)#y
            right = int(box[4] * color_frame.width)
            bottom = int(box[4] * color_frame.height)
            p1 = (left, top)
            p2 = (right, bottom)
            # draw box
            r, g, b = colors_hash[class_]
            cv2.rectangle(color_image, p1, p2, (int(r), int(g), int(b)), 2, 1)
            y = int(top/2)
            x = int(left/2)
            print("X: "+str(left)+" Y: "+str(top)+" Distance: "+str(depth_image[y,x]))#Depth Frame takes y first then x position

    cv2.namedWindow('RealSense', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    cv2.imshow('RealSense', color_image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

print("[INFO] stop streaming ...")
pipeline.stop()
```

This is what I get when compiling the script don't know if this gives any relevant information.

```
2022-06-14 12:52:14.058976: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
[INFO] Starting streaming...
[INFO] Camera ready.
[INFO] Loading model...
2022-06-14 12:52:18.251559: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2022-06-14 12:52:18.251871: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2022-06-14 12:52:18.257821: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: E-5CG1168PR1
2022-06-14 12:52:18.258228: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: E-5CG1168PR1
2022-06-14 12:52:18.258624: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
[INFO] Model loaded.
2022-06-14 12:52:18.431314: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:354] MLIR V1 optimization pass is not enabled
2022-06-14 12:52:20.576233: W tensorflow/core/grappler/costs/op_level_cost_estimator.cc:690] Error in PredictCost() for the op: op: "CropAndResize" attr { key: "T" value { type: DT_FLOAT } } attr { key: "extrapolation_value" value { f: 
0 } } attr { key: "method" value { s: "bilinear" } } inputs { dtype: DT_FLOAT shape { dim { size: -7 } dim { size: -10 } dim { size: -12 } dim { size: 576 } } } inputs { dtype: DT_FLOAT shape { dim { size: -33 } dim { size: 4 } } } inputs { dtype: DT_INT32 shape { dim { size: -33 } } } inputs { dtype: DT_INT32 shape { dim { size: 2 } } value { dtype: DT_INT32 tensor_shape { dim { size: 2 } } int_val: 14 } } device { type: "CPU" vendor: "GenuineIntel" model: "110" frequency: 2304 num_cores: 8 environment { key: "cpu_instruction_set" value: "SSE, SSE2" } environment { key: "eigen" value: "3.4.90" } l1_cache_size: 32768 l2_cache_size: 262144 l3_cache_size: 8388608 memory_size: 268435456 } outputs { dtype: DT_FLOAT shape { dim { size: -33 } dim { size: 14 } dim { size: 14 } dim { size: 576 } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `realsense` device does not have a `CUDA-enabled` `GPU`.
Running the object-detection deep-learning model takes up a lot of resources which slows down the frame-rate.

Some directions to explore to squeeze out higher frame-rate:

Add more in the comments if you think of any:

- Reduce size of `model-input`:

`config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 360, rs.format.bgr8, 30)`

In the code you seem not to be using the depth-image. Skipping the depth stream could probably save some CPU as well.

Comment: It might be because of the CUDA-enabled GPU that's causing the lag. Since I've tried on a computer with a gtx 1080 and still suffering from the low framerate. I don't think it's of the depth-image since it ran slowly even with that disabled and if you mean reduce size of the resolution it still suffers from low frame rate. So I do think it's because of CUDA but I seem to have problems installing that piece of software as well. Thanks for the help, been really illuminating.